# Find out the forces in members (as mentioned in the figure) of the truss by method of sections

Tags: civil-engineering, beam

I'm trying to find the forces in every member. But having a hard time resolving it. The Problem is to be solved by the Method of Sections of Truss.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forces on section b-b are calculated below.

1. $\sum F_J = 0, R_I= +8.33$
2. Draw section diagram with member forces indicated as shown in graph below.
   [image]
3. Write the external equilibrium equations for the section:

$\sum F_X = 0, F_{BA} + 0.8F_{EG} + F_{HG} = 0$ -----(1)

$\sum F_Y = 0, F_{BD} + 0.6F_{EG} - 8.33  = 0$ -----(2)

$\sum M_I = 0, 6F_{BA} + 8F_{BD} + 0.8_F{EG}*3 + 0.6F_{EG}*4 = 0$

-----> $6F_{BA} + 8F_{BD} +4.8F_{EG} = 0$ -----(3)

From (2), $F_{BD} = 8.33 - 0.6F_{EG}$ -----(2')

(2')->(3), $6F_{BA} + 66.64 = 0$

-----> $F_{BA} = -11.11$ (direction in reverse of direction assumed)

Plug $F_{BA}$ into (1), $-11.11 + 0.8F_{EG} + F_{HG} = 0$

-----> $ F_{EG} = 13.89 - 1.25F_{HG}$ ----->(1')

(1')->(2), $F_{BD} + 0.6*(13.89 - 1.25F_{HG} = 8.33$

-----> $F_{BD} = 0.75F_{HG}$ ----->(1")

As there are more unknowns than the external equilibrium equations available, we need to investigate an internal joint to get additional information. Let's select joint "E" (see figure below for direction of forces assumed),
[image]

At joint E, $\sum F_X = 0$ ------> $F_{EB} = F_{EG} = 13.89 -1.25F_{HG}$.

And, along member BE, $F_{BE} = F_{EB}$, thus,

at joint B, $F_{BE} = 13.89 - 1.25F_{HG}$ -----> (4)

and, $0.6F_{BE} - F_{BD} = 0$ ------>(5)

Plug (1") and (4) -> (5)

-----> $0.6*(13.89 - 1.25F_{HG}) - 0.75_F{HG} = 0$

-----> $F_{HG} = 5.56$

Finally, plug $F_{BA} = -11.11$ and $F_{HG} = 5.56$ into (1)

-----> $F_{EG} = 6.94$,

and $F_{HG}$ into (1')

-----> $F_{BD} = 4.17$

[image]
**Please check and advise for mistakes.**

Comment: nice job. what app did you use for drafting this?

Comment: OpenOffice "Drawing" tab. The download is free.

Comment: Thanks. I look it up.

Comment: You are welcome. Here is the download link. https://www.openoffice.org/download/

Comment: thanks, i downloaded it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is instead of section b-b (sectioning AB,BD, GE, GH), you need to take another section cc (sectioning AB,BD, DG, FG).

Then the second step is, to  calculate the reactions at J or  (preferably) I.

Then you take a section (e.g. a-a in my example below) and you draw the forces for each rod

[image]

Then the final step is to write equation for each node of a section. You can write equations for forces, but generally is best to work with the equilibrium of moments. NOTE: you can only write 3 equations for each section.

So for example for a-a you can write the moment equilibrium for points, A,D and F and you will find that they will be depended on only a few unknowns and the reaction at I.

$$\sum M_A = 0 \text{  (depended only on DF, FG)}$$
$$\sum M_D = 0 \text{  (depended only on AB, FG)}$$
$$\sum M_F = 0 \text{  (depended only on AD, AB)}$$

then you will do the same for the other section (c-c) that I've mentioned, and you will select points B, G and I.

When you write all this equations you will see that there are 6 equations and 6 unknowns (it might actually be even simpler than that).